# encoded URL construction fails in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a very simple problem. I want to construct a encoded url from an object. I've an object called "invitation". "invitation" has following fields, "message", "date", "name". I want to construct a following encoded string from this object. So when I use this url, it will pre-fill google mail's compose form.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&su=Party+on+date&body=%0Amessage%0Ahttp://localhost:3000/invitations/3%0Aname%0A&tf=1

I've declared a helper as shown below (which suppose to return an encoded string and can be use in a view). ..

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def google_mail_encoded_url(invite)
    uri = URI.parse('https://mail.google.com/u/0/?')
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form('view'=> "cm", 'fs' => "1", 'su' => "Party on " + invite.date, 'body' => "\nHi,\n" + invite.message + "\n" + invitations_url(invite))

    puts uri.to_s
  end
end
```

I tried following in rails console,

```
@invite = Invitations.where(:id => 10)
helper.google_mail_encoded_url(@invite) #just to see the output....
```

This fails with NameError: undefined local variable or method `invitations_url' for main:Object. Is this the correct way to call and construct encoded url? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the routes are not loaded when you open a console.

To be able to use them run the following in your console:

```
> include Rails.application.reload_routes!.first.url_helpers
 => Object 
> root_path
 => "/"
```